# find pairs of real numbers $x, y$ to satisfy this equation

Tags: quadratics

equation is:    $(x + y)^2 = (x + 3)(y − 3)$

I'm not asking for a solution, but an approach. How do I prove this kind of question? I have tried to arrange it so that it

is $x + y$ = ....

But I still get nothing, nothing intuitive at least. What is a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Hint: let $u=x+3, v=y-3$ then the equation reduces to $(u+v)^2=uv \iff u^2+uv+v^2=0$.

Comment: @MANMAID. Now it hasn't. But I had to set some other tag, and the best I could find was *quadratics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

By expanding we have 
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^2&=(x+3)(y-3)\\
\iff x^2+2xy+y^2&=xy-3x+3y-9\\
\iff x^2+xy+y^2+3x-3y+9&=0\\
\iff \tfrac12(x+y)^2+\tfrac12(x+3)^2+\tfrac12(y-3)^2&=0
\end{align*}
So we must have $$x+y=x+3=y-3=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the inequality: $ab \le \dfrac{(a+b)^2}{4}$ with $a = x+3, b = y-3$ you have: $(x+y)^2 \le \dfrac{(x+y)^2}{4}\implies (x+y)^2 \le 0 \implies x+y = ...$

Answer (score 0):

Hint by dxiv:

Set $u: = x +3; v: = y- 3$; then

$\star)$   $u^2 + uv + v^2 = 0$.

Consider the square:

$(u +v)^2 = u^2 + 2uv +v^2 \ge 0$.

Subtract $\star$ :

$\Rightarrow$  $uv \ge 0$.

Hence $\star$ implies :

$v= u = 0$, I.e. $x +3 = y - 3 = 0$.